# Create a Venn diagram showing the relations of three sets of quantum states

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, visualization

I've determined a number of probabilities pertaining to three subsets of the "magic simplex"  of quantum states described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5046, and certainly would like to have a pictorial representation of their interrelations--presumably, in the form of a Venn diagram (cf. Fig. 3 in cited paper).

One set--$A$, call it--is composed of those states, the density matrices for which have "positive-partial-transposes" (PPT). Its probability is $\frac{8 \pi}{27 \sqrt{3}} \approx 0.537422$.

Another set--$B$--consists of those states that pass a certain (mutually-orthogonal-bases [MUB]) test for entanglement. Its probability is $\frac{1}{6} \approx 0.16667$.

The third set--$C$--consists of states that pass another (Choi witness) test for entanglement. Its probability is also $\frac{1}{6} \approx 0.16667$.

The intersections of $A$ and $B$ and of $A$ and $C$
give conceptually-important "bound-entanglement" probabilities. Both amounts are $-\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4 \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log (27)}{18} \approx 0.00736862$.

$B \land C$ is $\frac{1}{9} \approx 0.11111$.

$B \lor C$ is  $\frac{2}{9} \approx 0.22222$.

Both $\neg B \land C$ and $B \land \neg C$ are $\frac{1}{18}$.

$A\land \neg B\land \neg C$ gives $\frac{1}{9} (8 - \log{3}) \approx 0.52268$.

$A \land B \land C$ is void.

So, I would like a (planar?) Venn-type diagram representing--as well as possible--the intersection and union relations between $A, B$ and $C$ and the larger set $D$ of probability 1, of which they are subsets.

An immediate idea would be to try to represent them by circles--but, I think, there is also an approach ("Euler diagrams" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) in which rectangles are employed.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some code to your question to help those of us with less maths knowledge and more mathematica knowledge understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to represent the relations between the three subsets of the larger set $D$ of probability 1, represented by a circle ($D$) centered at the origin $\{0,0\}$ of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

I used the circle-circle intersection formula for "the area of a general asymmetric lens obtained from circles of radii R and r and offset d" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lens.html)

```
-(1/2) Sqrt[(d + r - R) (d - r + R) (-d + r + R) (d + r + R)] + r^2 ArcCos[(d^2 + r^2 - R^2)/(2 d r)] + R^2 ArcCos[(d^2 - r^2 + R^2)/(2 d R)]
```

with the three radii

```
rA = Sqrt[(8 Pi/(27 Sqrt[3]))/Pi]; rB = Sqrt[1/6]; rC = Sqrt[1/6];
```

and the three overlap probabilities

```
overlapAC = -(4/9) + (4 \[Pi])/(27 Sqrt[3]) + Log[27]/18; overlapAB =  -(4/9) + (4 \[Pi])/(27 Sqrt[3]) + Log[27]/18; overlapBC = 1/9
```

The command

```
Solve[{inter[rA, rB, dAB] == overlapAB,inter[rA, rC, dAC] == overlapAC, inter[rB, rC, dBC]; == overlapBC}, {dAB, dAC, dBC}]
```

was not successful, and one could use FindRoot.

However, I did (am doing) a random search within $D$, constraining the possible locations for the center of $A$ to lie within a circle--again centered at the origin--of radius $1-\frac{8 \pi}{27 \sqrt{3}}$, in order that it not extend outside the overall (probability 1) set $D$. Similarly, the origins of the circles representing $B$ and $C$ have to lie within circles of radii $\frac{5}{6}$.

I tried minimizing a function (many possible candidates) of the fits of the overlap areas to the given probabilities.

The result is given by the webpage

[Venn-diagram attempt](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/9970135c-7d23-40fd-89bb-4f1354a19db7)

I would appreciate comments as to Mathematica commands for coloring/labeling ,...the sets so as to highlight the areas of intersection--or any alternative approaches to addressing the underlying question.