# How can I label these three circles as A, B, C?

Tags: graphics, labeling

I have this code (based on that of flinty in his/her answer to [Can one employ Disk with symbolic arguments in equations--and, if not, how might the equations in question be formulated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222530/can-one-employ-disk-with-symbolic-arguments-in-equations-and-if-not-how-might))

```
Graphics[({Disk[{x1, 0}, 1/Sqrt[\[Pi]/(
  4702531/4247100 - (4 \[Pi])/(27 Sqrt[3]) - ArcCosh[97]/(
   54 Sqrt[3]) - (Sqrt[3] Log[2])/Log[81])]], 
 Disk[{x2, 0}, 
  1/9 Sqrt[(27 + Sqrt[3] Log[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]])/\[Pi]]], 
 Disk[{x3, 0}, (2 Sqrt[2])/(3 3^(3/4))]} /. 
Disk -> Circle) /. {x1 -> 0.6331929391119231`, x2 -> 0.6846889868196268`, x3 -> 0.02782220589364115`}]
```

yielding the output

[image]

I want to label the circles A, B, C in the indicated order.

How can this be accomplished effectively?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** We can use the function `A[R, r, d]` from [Eric Weistein, "Circle-Circle Intersection" on Math World](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) for the area of the asymmetric lens in the intersection of two circles with radii `R` and `r` and centered at `{0, 0}` and `{d, 0}`, respectively. (See also [this related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204314/125).)

```
ClearAll[A]
A[R_, r_, d_] := r^2 ArcCos[(d^2 + r^2 - R^2)/(2 d r)] + 
  R^2 ArcCos[(d^2 + R^2 - r^2)/(2 d R)] - 
  Sqrt[(-d + r + R) (d + r - R) (d - r + R) (d + r + R)]/2
```

Three disks with non-empty pairwise intersections:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
{pa, pb, pc} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3];
{ra, rb, rc} = Sqrt[{pa, pb, pc}/Pi];

pab = RandomReal[{0, Min[pa, pb]}];
pac = RandomReal[{0, Min[pa, pc]}];
pbc = RandomReal[{0, Min[pb, pc]}];
```

We fix the center of disk `"A"` and use `A[R,r,d]` with `FindRoot` for disk pairs `AB`, `AC` and `BC`:

```
{dab, dac, dbc} = x /. FindRoot[A[##2, x] - #, {x, #3}] & @@@ 
  {{pab, ra, rb}, {pac, ra, rc}, {pbc, rb, rc}}
```

> ```
>  {0.325653, 0.577687, 0.481694}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use `NArgMin` to get the same values:

```
NArgMin[{Abs[A[ra, rb, x] - pab] + Abs[A[ra, rc, y] - pac] + 
   Abs[A[rb, rc, z] - pbc], x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
>  {0.325653, 0.577687, 0.481694}
> ```

Placed on the horizontal axis (with appropriate translation for disk `"C"`), the pairs `AB` and `BC` have the correct intersections:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], Red, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, ra], Blue, Disk[{dab, 0}, rb], Green, 
  Disk[{dbc, 0} + {xdab, 0}, rc], Black, Text["A", {0, 0}], 
  Text["B", {dab, 0}], Text["C", {dbc, 0} + {dab, 0}] }]
```

[image]

We fix  disks `"A"` and `"B"` and rotate disk `"C"` around disk `"B"` (this preserves the intersection area between disks `"C"` and `"B"`) until its intersection with disk `"A"` has the prescribed area:

```
theta = NArgMin[{Abs[A[ra, rc, Norm[{dab, 0} + dbc {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]] - pac], 
  0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t]
```

> ```
> 4.6985
> ```

Show all three disks together:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], Red, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, ra], Blue, Disk[{dab, 0}, rb], Green, 
  Disk[RotationTransform[theta]@{dbc, 0} + {dab, 0}, rc], Black, 
  Text["A", {0, 0}], Text["B", {dab, 0}], 
  Text["C", RotationTransform[theta]@{dbc, 0} + {dab, 0}] }]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
labels = {"A", "B", "C"};
Graphics[(MapIndexed[{#, Text[labels[[#2[[1]]]], #[[1]]]} &,
   {Disk[{x1, 0}, 1/Sqrt[π/(4702531/4247100 - (4 π)/(27 Sqrt[3]) - 
            ArcCosh[97]/(54 Sqrt[3]) - (Sqrt[3] Log[2])/Log[81])]], 
    Disk[{x2, 0}, 1/9 Sqrt[(27 + Sqrt[3] Log[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]])/π]], 
    Disk[{x3, 0}, (2 Sqrt[2])/(3 3^(3/4))]}] /. Disk -> Circle) /. 
 {x1 -> 0.6331929391119231`, x2 -> 0.6846889868196268`, x3 -> 0.02782220589364115`}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Guess it could be more unequivocal about A and B. Well, in any case, I'm now not very satisfied by the positioning of the circles, since the referenced flinty code--based on limited intersection data--does not reveal that within circle C, the ("bound-entangled") part belonging to B should not, in fact, lie entirely within the part belonging to A. Challenging to extend the flinty code to reveal this, though.

Comment: @Paul, please see  if the approach in the update  gives the desired picture for the input parameters underlying the picture in your post.

Comment: Thanks again, kgir. Of course, the new function  A[R, r, d] is a nice addition. Without further going into the specifics of the new coding (much of it not really within my skill level), it seems quite striking that the new circles (now nicely labeled) are highly incomparable in relative sizes with the original ones (which I think are more in keeping with the data). So, I suspect something is amiss in the sizing of the new set of circles. However, I also now see that the new circles seem more properly situated, in line with my earlier criticism of the intersections of A and B with C in original

Comment: Puzzling! Can measures of fit be compared--or is there such a measure for the new plot?

Comment: OK, I need to pay closer attention to the detailed analysis here.

Comment: I've made some efforts to apply your code to the specific situation addressed by the flinty code--and the areas of the resultant three circles do seem appropriate. Not quite sure, however, as to the appropriateness of the sizes of  intersections. More pondering to be done. Incidentally, the THREE-way intersection should equal 2/121 = 0.0165289. Probably too much to try to incorporate that. In fact, I have formulas for all the (256) boolean combinations of the three sets. However, many involve negation--which I think would require a fourth "supercircle" (area 1), properly containing other 3.

Comment: @Paul, i think we do not have enough freedom to get both pairwise and three-way intersections right with disks.

Comment: I guess one would have to incorporate additional parameters into the modeling. (Easier said than done.)

Comment: Here's a related (a year ago) posting of mine, I dug up--with somewhat different data, plus a fourth circle enclosing the other three https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198019/create-a-venn-diagram-showing-the-relations-of-three-sets-of-quantum-states